# No comprendo esta comparacion entre listas y strings

Tags: python

Estaba continuando un proyecto muy básico para automatizar la clasificación de textos en diferentes .txt. En especifico quería quitar una lista de palabras. Después de estar un rato tratando cosas como:

```
if not (for i in List) in Plbr_Flt:
```

o

```
if not any(List[0,5] in Plbr_Flt):
```

Me termine rindiendo y buscando en internet, hasta que encontré una publicación donde alguien preguntaba exactamente lo mismo. La respuesta que le dieron funciona, pero no logro entender porque, y en el susodicho post no es explicado. La respuesta era algo así:

```
if any(x in Plbr_Flt for x in List):
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Esa expresión combina dos cosas:

- `any()`. Es una función que espera como parámetro un *iterable*, es decir, algo por lo que pueda iterar (podría ser una lista, un diccionario, un conjunto, un generador... o como ocurre en tu caso una *expresión generadora*). El caso es que la función retorna `True` si uno cualquiera de los elementos del iterable es `True` (o *truthy*, que significa que puede ser considerado como cierto al convertirle a booleano).

  La función además hace "cortocircuito" si es necesario, que significa que tan pronto como uno de los elementos sobre los que está iterando salga `True`, ya no sigue mirando más. Sólo si ha agotado el iterable sin encontrar ningún `True`, retornará `False`.
- Lo que está dentro de los paréntesis de `any()`, que es una *expresión generadora*. Este tipo de expresiones tiene una sintaxis muy similar a las *comprensiones de listas*, pero en lugar de ir encerrada entre corchetes, va encerrada entre paréntesis (que pueden omitirse cuando la expresión se está usando como único parámetro de una función, como en este caso).

  La expresión generadora, a diferencia de una comprensión de listas, no evalúa el bucle completo, sino que es *lazy*, es decir, va devolviendo un elemento de cada vez, sin necesidad de computar todos de antemano.

Así pues, cada vez que `any()` intente iterar, la expresion generadora calculará el siguiente elemento y se lo devolverá. Si ese elemento es `True`,  `any()` terminará y devolverá `True`.

En tu caso la expresión generadora es `x in Plbr_Flt for x in List`, que significa que se irá iterando sobre la lista `List` y en cada iteración se extrae un elemento que se guarda en `x`, para después evaluar la primera parte de la expresión, que es `x in Plbr_Flt`.

Juntando todo: tan pronto como un elemento `x` de `List` aparezca en `Plbr_Flt`, la expresión generadora generará un `True`, y `any()` terminará con resultado `True`.

Lo bonito de esta sintaxis es que al final casi es texto en inglés. Si lo lees traduciéndolo viene a decir "Si cualquier x está en la lista Plbr_Flt, para los x de la lista List, entonces..."

### Bonus

Lo mismo puede escribirse usando una sintaxis más "normal" (más o menos como habría que hacerlo en C). Esta forma es también más "fea" (o a mi me lo parece, una vez me he acostumbrado a la expresividad de la forma "pythónica"):

```
encontrado = False
for x in List:
  if x in Plbr_Flt:
     encontrado = True
     break
if encontrado:
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if any(x in Plbr_Flt for x in List):
```

`List` es una lista, asi que `for x in List` recorre la lista y va entregado elemento por elemento en la variable x.

Por cada elemento entregado se ejecuta la expresión `x in Plbr_Flt`. Esta simplemente chequea si `x` es parte de `Plbr_Flt` (presumiblemente una lista, tupla, set o similar). Si se cumple la condición, se genera un `True`. Si no, un `False`.

Lo que hace la función `any` es tomar un iterable, como una lista, tupla, etc. y ver si alguno de sus elementos es `True`. Un elemento es `True` si es un número distinto de cero o una cadena, lista, etc. no vacía.

En castellano, el `if` evalúa si alguno de los elementos de List también es parte de `Plbr_Flt`.